# Retopology rough edges with subdivision

Tags: modeling, mesh, retopology

I'm trying to make the retopology for my character but some faces' edges don't want to curve in when i subdivide the surface, any tips? [image][image][image][image]

Comment: try to recalculate the normals (Shift N), or merge by distance (M), or check for inner faces

Comment: As Moonboots says it looks like a normal direction problem. If you enable backface culling, you will instantly see these kind of problems. https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/4/4/6/4469ea6fb5678587762b6f12ec69ab7036e43d4d.png

Comment: thanks for the help <3